# typescript meaning of "{text, comp} : NavProps & Comp<NavProps>"?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and encounter some codes like the following.

```
export interface Comp<T> {
  comp: (props: T) => JSX.Element;
}

export interface NavProps {
  text: string;
}

export default function Nav({text, comp}: NavProps & Comp<NavProps>) {
  let renderProps: NavProps = {
    text: text,
  };
  return comp(renderProps);
}
```

Some namings can be confusing but I don't want to mess up the working codes.

What do the codes intend to do? Particularly, what is this? `{text, comp}: NavProps & Comp<NavProps>`

Answer (score 0):

This code in general looks like a [React](https://reactjs.org/) component.

`{text, comp}: NavProps & Comp<NavProps>` is declaring function's parameter but using a [destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#destructuring).

Basically

```
export default function Nav({text, comp}: NavProps & Comp<NavProps>) {
  let renderProps: NavProps = {
    text: text,
  };
  return comp(renderProps);
}
```

would be the same as:

```
export default function Nav(props: NavProps & Comp<NavProps>) {
  let renderProps: NavProps = {
    text: props.text,
  };
  return props.comp(renderProps);
}
```